# Convert Hex to Byte with big string

Tags: java, byte

I tried the different ways to convert hex to byte, there are four methods in the code, three of them I comment it out, only one there is no error when I run it, but I confused that when I repeated to run the code, it gave me the different result (should be generate "byte").

There is a question is when I use "method1", it gave me the result (byte), but once I changed to "method2", it will not generate the result, I don't know why. I thought it should generate same result, when I have same string.

```
public class Convert {
/**
 * @param args
 * @throws IOException 
 */

// String everything;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    //String everything;
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    BufferedReader br = null;
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\TEMP1\\Doctor.txt"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        try {
            line = br.readLine();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        while (line != null) {
            sb.append(line);
            sb.append('\n');
            line = br.readLine();
        }

        //*********Method 1****************
            //String r="1ee079746828d7c6f9af46f93c1ef2555ff4b14b2378ad53a258d18dc6a8363fb57f3448783833722bd9ef291ba53153afca31a96de404755e78f68b76fd5a77e4be3b984ea25244842e92a8ed40da1f1a588fb3da26b8bc21d74cd8476534f26ee454df086567c4d7cf3334f794cede41a9b051a5c393a35584afcf";
            //byte[] b = new BigInteger(r,16).toByteArray();
            //System.out.println("Byte for public key: "+b); 



        //*********Method 2****************
            //String r2 = sb.toString();
            //System.out.println("Doctor contect file: "+r2);
            //byte[] b = new BigInteger(r2,16).toByteArray();
            //System.out.println("Byte for public key: "+b); 

        //********Method 3*****************

            String r="1ee079746828d7c6f9af46f93c1ef2555ff4b14b2378ad53a258d18dc6a8363fb57f3448783833722bd9ef291ba53153afca31a96de404755e78f68b76fd5a77e4be3b984ea25244842e92a8ed40da1f1a588fb3da26b8bc21d74cd8476534f26ee454df086567c4d7cf3334f794cede41a9b051a5c393a35584afcf";  
            int len = r.length();
            byte[] data = new byte[len / 2];
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
                data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(r.charAt(i), 16) << 4)
                                 + Character.digit(r.charAt(i+1), 16));
                System.out.println(data);
        }


        //********Method4******************
        /*
            String r2 = sb.toString();
            int len = r2.length();
            byte[] data = new byte[len / 2];
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
                data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(r2.charAt(i), 16) << 4)
                                     + Character.digit(r2.charAt(i+1), 16));
                System.out.println(data);
            }
        */






        //String r=everything;

       // String r="1ee079746828d7c6f9af46f93c1ef2555ff4b14b2378ad53a258d18dc6a8363fb57f3448783833722bd9ef291ba53153afca31a96de404755e78f68b76fd5a77e4be3b984ea25244842e92a8ed40da1f1a588fb3da26b8bc21d74cd8476534f26ee454df086567c4d7cf3334f794cede41a9b051a5c393a35584afcf";
       // double convert=Double.parseDouble(r);
       //  long convert=(long)(Integer.parseInt(r,32)&0xFF);
       // byte convert=Byte.parseByte(r,32);
       // byte convert=Integer.parseInt(everything,16);
      // System.out.println("Byte for public key: "+convert);

    } finally {
        br.close();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Unless this is homework, use DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(yourhexstring); to convert a hex string to a byte array.

Comment: Out of the 90-ish lines of code you've posted, only 7 are relevant to the question. Please focus on only posting *relevant* code next time.

Answer (score 3):

You're printing the result of calling `toString` on a `byte[]`. That's not going to give you what you want.

For diagnostic purposes, use `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(data))`. And do that at the *end* of the loop rather than within it:

```
for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
   ...
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(data));
```

There are plenty of alternative approaches to parsing a hex string, mind you. I don't personally like the idea of using an XML-focused API (as recommended in the question comments) when you're not dealing with XML, but it would certainly work - and any number of third party APIs have hex conversion routines.

EDIT: As noted in comments, I believe your hex conversion code is *also* broken at the moment - but that should probably be fixed by using a prebuilt one from elsewhere. The main purpose of this answer was to explain why you're getting results such as "[B@40a0dcd9". Once you can *see* the data, you can verify it.

Comment: I'm quite certain that he wanted `data[ii/2]` in the loop, thous seeing what it currently did.

Comment: @AngeloNeuschitzer: Yes, you're probably right - but the first step is being able to see the data actually produced :) (At the moment it would produce a horrible looking string which did nothing useful.)

Comment: @JonSkeet - While DatatypeConverter is part of the javax.xml package, it does have the advantages that:  1. It is a standard part of the JVM - no 3rd party package required. 2.  It provides a one-liner to convert a hex string to byte array, AFAIK the only utility in the standard libraries to do so.

Comment: @AngeloNeuschitzer: Ah, re-read your comment and I see what you mean. I'd suggest that taking the `System.out.println` out of the loop entirely makes sense.

Comment: @lreeder: That's really only *one* advantage, as far as I can tell. (Or rather, one advantage over using other code in the JRE, and a different advantage over using 3rd party code.) Personally I wouldn't mind picking up a third-party package to avoid using types in odd places - especially as chances are that any decent sized Java project will already be including a library which has a conversion for this.

Comment: but for the "method 4" in the code, it has a error. whatever i change 16 to 32, it still gives me same one
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 249
 at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
 at Convert.main(Convert.java:77)

Comment: @user2141529: I didn't look at any of the commented out code - that's a different problem, and should be asked in a different question, with a *short* but complete program demonstrating *only* the problem. (I suspect it's quite simple, but you should only ask one question per post.)

Comment: thank you Jon, i will try to solve the problem before i post another question.

Thank you guys for helping. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure on why you do that, so this answer may not reflect your intend.

I tried to comprehend your stuff and came to the conclusion that you want to split that string into two character blocks, treat them as a hex number and convert them to a byte.

That wont work, as the second block `e0` is larger that `Byte.MAX_VALUE`. So, heres my latest guess on what could be the code that you are looking for (using Integer).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String r = "1ee079746828d7c6f9af46f93c1ef2555ff4b14b2378ad53a258d18dc6a8363fb57f3448783833722bd9ef291ba53153afca31a96de404755e78f68b76fd5a77e4be3b984ea25244842e92a8ed40da1f1a588fb3da26b8bc21d74cd8476534f26ee454df086567c4d7cf3334f794cede41a9b051a5c393a35584afcf";
    char[] rA = r.toCharArray();
    int len = r.length();
    int[] data = new int[len / 2];

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
        String base = "#" + rA[i] + rA[i+1];
        System.out.println("base: " + base);
        data[i / 2] = Integer.decode(base);
        System.out.println(data[i/2]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Angelo, thanks for your help, but i really have to convert it to byte.!!

Answer (score 0):

After reading your question again, it seems that you describe that when you use the String directly (`method1`) it works, but if you read if from a file (`method2`) it does not.

The reason is simple: You add a `\n` at the end of the String you read from file. You do not do so in your `method1`.

Comment: You append it. Manually. In this line: `sb.append('\n');`